# How to populate Angularjs $scope variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
mapApp.controller("myController", function ($scope,$http) {
            $scope.namePlaceHolder= "Name";
            $scope.name = "";
};
```

I bound a scope variable to an html input as follows.

```
<input id="foo" type="text" placeholder="{{namePlaceHolder}}" ng-model="name" value="{{name}}"/>
```

If a user types something in text box the $scope.name property changes. But when I change it using javascript the $scope.name data doesn't change.

```
on(document.getElementById("button"), "click", function (e) {
        document.getElementById("foo").value = "ascd...";
})
```

This code does not populate $scope.name data.

Comment: You don't manipulate html directly in AngularJS. Why do you want to do this.

Comment: did you mean getElementById("foo")?

Comment: getElementById("foo") edited

Comment: @Chandermani, sometimes I change "foo" input element in javascript code. So in this stuation, changed data should populate in $scope

Comment: For that you should use directive, and do $scope.apply() after the change. Since angularjs does not know about your change.

Comment: Try to manipulate the model within the angular world unless you have special requirement ( 3rd party JS  lib integration). Here is a [jsFiddle demo for accessing angular world member from javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/3rXRL/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Accesing scope from external element:

```
on(document.getElementById("button"), "click", function (e) {
            var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("foo")).scope();
            scope.name = "hello, World!";
    })
```

Comment: `var scope = angular.element("#foo").scope();` is a shorter notation

Answer (score 7):

Accessing and apply scope from external element:

JS:

```js
on(document.getElementById("button"), "click", function (e) {
            var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("foo")).scope();
            scope.name = "hello, World!";
            scope.$apply();
    })
```

Comment: i decide to 50+ score to your answer and  10000+ to you

Answer (score 4):

Beside multiple other things. Here [Prototypal Inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) kicks in, which does overwrite your `namePlaceholder` property on the `$scope` object since your `<form ...>` does create a new `$scope` which inherits from your controller. Therefore you should always "[use a dot](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot)".

E.g.

```
$scope.placeHolders = {
    name: "something"
};
```

and then

```
<input placeholder="{{placeholders.name}}">
```

Another thing is that you "left" the angular word when manipulating an angular variable outside of angular and therefore have to call `angular.element(document.getElementById("foo")).scope().$apply(...)` to "get back" in the angular world from your own JS.

## But the better solution

```
mapApp.controller("myController", function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.placeHolders = {
        name: 'Name'
    };
    $scope.selected = {
        name: ''
    };
    $scope.click = function() {
       $scope.selected.name = "something ...";
    };
};

<input ng-model="selected.name" placeholder="{{ placeHolders.name }}" ...>
<button ng-click="click()"></button>
```

Answer (score 3):

DOM manipulations from within Angular should always come from **directives** - this allows for clean separation of code. In your case, you would never change the `value` attribute of that input, you would modify the `ng-model` so the changes will be reflected in your `$scope` variable.

So, in your above element of ID `button`, use an `ng-click`

```
ng-click="changeValue()"

//In controller
$scope.changeValue = function() {
    $scope.name = "ascd...";
}
```